# How to remove full page reload

Tags: reactjs

I have an a link in the return section of a react component and when
I click on the link the whole page reloads. I don't want the whole page
to reload. How can I correct this?

```
        const Tester = () => {
          ...
          ...
          ...
          
          if (showComponent) {
            return (
              <div className={classes.root}>
                <div className={classes.messageWrap}>                 
                  <a
                    href=''
                    onClick={() => toggle()}
                    className={classes.messageText}
                  >
                    {userType}
                  </a>        
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          }
          return null
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your click handler will receive an `event` argument. You can prevent the event from propagating up and/or prevent the default behavior (in this case, navigating) by calling `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()` respectively.

```js
const handleClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // do other stuff.
}

<a href='' onClick={handleClick}>...</a>
```

I would suggest, however, that a `<button>` makes more sense semantically if you're not using it to navigate.

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  // do stuff. no need to fight the default browser behavior.
}

<button onClick={handleClick}>...</button>
```

Comment: When I applied this I got an error message saying " Parameter e implicitly has an any type'

Comment: That's a typescript issue, not a javascript issue. If you're using typescript you have to declare the `e` parameter's type.

Comment: That's correct. I use typescript and i fixed the issue.